# Group based questions and answers - Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, survey

I am looking to created a voting system for my site.  I am having a little trouble deciding on how to model it.

At present I have models like so:

```
Group has many users
```

On each group page it will have the same question, for example:

"What feature would you like next?"

Each group would have a the same set of answers which can be voted on.  I am going to use the Thumbs Up gem to allow answers to be voted on.

The amount of groups is extremely large, somewhere in the region of 5000.

I was thinking about modelling it like so:

```
Answer has many Responses
Response belongs to Group, Answer and is voteable (acts_as_voteable with Thumbs Up gem)
```

Could anyone give suggestions on how other wise model this questions and answers?  For some reason this doesn't feel correct.

Essentially mutltiple groups will have the same question and answers except different poll results.  I want to try and avoid creating a poll and questions for each group as this would result in over 100,000 records in the database.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

"Essentially mutltiple groups will have the same question and answers except different poll results. I want to try and avoid creating a poll and questions for each group as this would result in over 100,000 records in the database."

As I understood it you have Questions with a fixed set of Possible Answers, and you store the result in Response?

I would go with a 1:n relationship between Question and Answer,
and probably n:m between Group and Question, this way you can "reuse" Questions in multiple Groups.

Comment: Yea.  Pretty much.  So it would be ok design to give each answer a response per group?  So a response would be long to a group and answer.

Comment: Why not? if that's what you need. I find the distinction between response and answer a bit confusing, though, maybe you find a better wording for that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The distinction between the response and the answer is if each group was to vote on the same answer objects then the vote count would be across every group and not a per group basis.  So my reason for a response object attached to the answer and group would be to keep track of the votes on a certain answer per group.  If you get what I mean.  :)  Cheers

Comment: Yeah, I got that, I just think the naming is not very descriptive.